# Popup shows the data twice when exporting a specific layer to OpenLayers with QGIS2Web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I've got a problem when exporting a specific layer to OpenLayers with QGIS2Web.

This specific layer is a Parcel or Lot and has subdivision parcels or subdivision lots within. The main parcel has data as area, owner, location... and same data for each subdivision lot.

However, when I export it to OpenLayers and click on a parcel it shows me the Main parcel data and the subdivision lot data, so because they are the same owner and same location and I see the very much the same information except for the area.

But, I export it to Leaflet it works as I want it to work. When I click on a parcel it shows me just one set of data. The subdivision lot.

I really want to use OpenLayers so I would like to know if someone has a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you update to either of the recent experimental versions of qgis2web (3.8.0 or 3.9.0), there is a new option for each layer, which allows you completely to disable popups. Thanks to @ricckli for creating this feature! I don't have a timescale for a non-experimental release, but hopefully soon.

You can then disable popups on one of your two layers, and get the behaviour you want.